C++ class member's specialization with nontype arguments
I need to define a class with nontype template parameters and specialize one of its function member's. The code below is a reasonable simplification of what I need to do (we can assume this is c++11 but I don't think the C++ standard is the issue here).
template <class T, std::size_t LIMIT=100>
struct A {

  std::array<T,LIMIT> array;

  void print (T value) {
    std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  }

};


template<>
void A<float>::print(float value) {
  
  std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
  std::cout << value*10.0 << std::endl;
}


int main (int argc, const char** argv) {

  A<float> a;
  a.print(23.3);
}

When I compile it (g++ 9.4.), I get this error:
test.cpp: In member function ‘void A<T, LIMIT>::print(T) [with T = float; long unsigned int LIMIT = 100]’:
test.cpp:20:16: error: ‘LIMIT’ was not declared in this scope
   20 |   std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
      |                ^~~~~

which is quite surprising since it seems to me that the compile knows very well what LIMIT is ("long unsigned int LIMIT = 100").
If I implement the function this way:
template<>
void A<float, std::size_t LIMIT=100>::print(float value) {
  
  std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
  std::cout << value*10.0 << std::endl;
}

I instead get this other error:
test.cpp:18:36: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   18 | void A<float, std::size_t LIMIT=100>::print(float value) {
      |                                    ^
test.cpp:18:56: error: ‘print’ is not a template function
   18 | void A<float, std::size_t LIMIT=100>::print(float value) {
      |   

I suspect there are some limitations on function members specializations and nontype parameters that I am unaware of.
PS: this is an example of some code that will run in an embedded system, so I actually need nontype params, that's non-negotiable.
I tried without success
template<>
void A<float>::print(float value) {
  
  std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
  std::cout << value*10.0 << std::endl;
}

template<>
void A<float, std::size_t LIMIT>::print(float value) {
  
  std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
  std::cout << value*10.0 << std::endl;
}

and
template<>
void A<float, std::size_t LIMIT=100>::print(float value) {
  
  std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
  std::cout << value*10.0 << std::endl;
}


You can partially specialize the class for the type template argument float.

LIMIT is only defined within context of definition of A class template, but you are defining a function out of that context. Same way you cannot refer to T anywhere outside of class template definition.
The usual solution for types is to provide a name alias
using value_type = T;

so for non-type template parameter I'd do a simple static constexpr value in class:
template <class T, std::size_t LIMIT=100>
struct A {
    constexpr static std::size_t limit_v = LIMIT;
//...
};

// and then in definition you can do
template<>
void A<float>::print(float value) {
  
  std::cout << limit_v << std::endl;
  std::cout << value*10.0 << std::endl;
}

See it online

Heads up: If you make it A<float, 10> a; it will select the non-specialized print function.

@TedLyngmo Good call, an actual partial specialisation (like in the other answer) would address that if it is an issue.

Good catch, @TedLyngmo. I suppose that's because if the class is instantiated for float, the compile does not even look for a specialization of a method for the same type (the class is complete anyway). In my case I solved this "issue" by just declaring the function print in the template without implementing it, and that forces the developer (me) to write a specialization for each type, which was exactly the goal.

@tappara "forces the developer (me) to write a specialization for each type" - A specialization of the print function only that covers all LIMITs? You could write an answer to show how you did that too.

you can for instance partially specialize the class:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, std::size_t LIMIT=100>
struct A 
{
    std::array<T,LIMIT> array;

    void print (T value) 
    {
        std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};

template <std::size_t LIMIT>
struct A<float,LIMIT>
{
    void print (float value) 
    {
        std::cout << LIMIT << std::endl;
        std::cout << 10.0*value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main (int argc, const char** argv) 
{
  A<float>{}.print(23.35);
  A<int>{}.print(23);
}

Demo

Update: This solution is not perfect in case one wants to specialize only one method among others. For instance, if the initial  struct A has also a method foo, one has to define it in the specialization for T=float otherwise it won't exist in the specialization. So, there is likely a better solution that avoids this.

Update:
Actually, you could simply put the common code in a base class BaseA and make A inherits from it with potential methods intended to be specialized via template specialization for some types:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, std::size_t LIMIT>
struct BaseA
{
    std::array<T,LIMIT> array;

    void foo ()
    {
        std::cout << "foo\n"; 
    }
};

template <class T, std::size_t LIMIT=100>
struct A : BaseA<T,LIMIT>
{
    void print (float value) 
    {
        std::cout << "[GENERIC]  LIMIT: " << LIMIT << " value: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

template <std::size_t LIMIT>
struct A<float,LIMIT> : BaseA<float,LIMIT>
{
    void print (float value) 
    {
        std::cout << "[SPECIAL]  LIMIT: " << LIMIT << " value: " << 10.0*value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main (int argc, const char** argv) 
{
    A<float>{}.print(23.35);
    A<int>{}.print(23);

    A<float,10>{}.print(23.35);
    A<int,10>{}.print(23);

    A<float>{}.foo();
    A<int>{}.foo();
}

Demo
Note: after second thought, the CRTP would be overkill in this case, even though it is an interesting (and curious) pattern.

You can specialise members of class template. cppreference has examples of that (look at 3rd code block under "Members of specializations").

@Yksisarvinen, you're right indeed; I just rephrase my answer by just providing a partial specialization.

But I guess your solution scales better when one wants to specialize only one method, which seems to be the OP intent in the first place.

The primary template and the specialization could inherit from a class that defines foo. CRTP may come in handy in that case.

@TedLyngmo, yes indeed, I also thought about a CRTP based solution but I eventually went for a simple answer.

@edrezen thanks for the answer, but the goal here is to specialize just a method or two. In real life this class defines a bunch of data processing that I could generalize using the STL. Unfortunately a few methods need specialization, hence my question. I'll look into CRPT, by if you want to provide some ideas/suggestions/solutions, I'll surely appreciate that.
